# Array-based queue implementation

Tags: java, queue

Here I have implemented a queue. Is this a correct, efficient queue implementation? what issues are there if any and what can be done to make it better?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Queue2{
    private int amountInQueue;
    private int[] queue;
    private int rearIndex;
    private int frontIndex;

    public Queue2(){
        amountInQueue = 0;
        queue = new int[10];
        rearIndex = 0;
        frontIndex = 0;
    }

    public Queue2(int queueCapacity){
        amountInQueue = 0;
        queue = new int[queueCapacity];
        rearIndex = 0;
        frontIndex = 0;
    }

    public void enqueue(int valueToAdd){
        if(amountInQueue == queue.length){
            throw new FullQueueException();
        }
        else if(rearIndex == queue.length -1){
            rearIndex = 0;
            queue[rearIndex] = valueToAdd;
            amountInQueue++;
        }
        else if(amountInQueue == 0){
            queue[rearIndex] = valueToAdd;
            amountInQueue++;
        }
        else{
            rearIndex++;
            queue[rearIndex] = valueToAdd;
            amountInQueue++;
        }
    }

    public int dequeue(){
        int frontValue = frontIndex;
        if(amountInQueue == 0){
            throw new EmptyQueueException();
        }
        if(frontIndex == queue.length -1){
            frontValue = queue[frontIndex];
            frontIndex = 0;
            amountInQueue--;
        }
        else{
            frontValue = queue[frontIndex];
            frontIndex++;
            amountInQueue--;
        }
        return frontValue;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return amountInQueue == 0;
    }

    public int valueAtRear(){
        return queue[rearIndex];
    }

    public int valueAtFront(){
        return queue[frontIndex];
    }

    public int currentSize(){
      return amountInQueue;
    }

  class FullQueueException extends RuntimeException{
      public FullQueueException(){
          super("You cannot add values to a queue that is full");
      }
  }

  class EmptyQueueException extends RuntimeException{
      public EmptyQueueException(){
          super("You cannot remove values from a queue that is empty");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your queue is neither threadsafe nor concurrent. You might want to offer a take operation that blocks while the queue is empty and a put operation that blocks while the queue is full. The best implementation I know would be a (blocking) RingBuffer. You can check out the LMAX Disruptor, a horribly overengineered and rather complicated datastructure that's supposed to be one of the best. I have learned a lot when I dissected it.

Comment: @Traubenfuchs that's an answer

Answer (score 2):

#### Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

> ```
>     public void enqueue(int valueToAdd){
>         if(amountInQueue == queue.length){
>             throw new FullQueueException();
>         }
>         else if(rearIndex == queue.length -1){
>             rearIndex = 0;
>             queue[rearIndex] = valueToAdd;
>             amountInQueue++;
>         }
>         else if(amountInQueue == 0){
>             queue[rearIndex] = valueToAdd;
>             amountInQueue++;
>         }
>         else{
>             rearIndex++;
>             queue[rearIndex] = valueToAdd;
>             amountInQueue++;
>         }
>     }
> ```

There's some duplicate code here.  Consider

```
    public void enqueue(int valueToAdd) {
        if(amountInQueue == queue.length) {
            throw new FullQueueException();
        }

        if (rearIndex == queue.length -1) {
            rearIndex = 0;
        }
        else if (amountInQueue == 0) {
            frontIndex = 0;
            rearIndex = 0;
        }
        else{
            rearIndex++;
        }

        queue[rearIndex] = valueToAdd;
        amountInQueue++;
    }
```

You don't need to use an `else` after you `throw` an exception, as it will leave the function immediately.

More importantly, other than the exceptional case, all the cases have the same two lines.  So take them out of the `if`/`else` construct.  In the empty queue case, there's nothing left.  You can clear the front and rear indexes if you want.  Or you can remove that case entirely.

> ```
>     public int dequeue(){
>         int frontValue = frontIndex;
>         if(amountInQueue == 0){
>             throw new EmptyQueueException();
>         }
>         if(frontIndex == queue.length -1){
>             frontValue = queue[frontIndex];
>             frontIndex = 0;
>             amountInQueue--;
>         }
>         else{
>             frontValue = queue[frontIndex];
>             frontIndex++;
>             amountInQueue--;
>         }
>         return frontValue;
>     }
> ```

Similarly, this could just be

```
    public int dequeue(){
        if (amountInQueue == 0) {
            throw new EmptyQueueException();
        }

        frontValue = queue[frontIndex];
        amountInQueue--;
        frontIndex++;
        if (frontIndex == queue.length) {
            frontIndex = 0;
        }

        return frontValue;
    }
```

You don't have to set the `return` value before the exceptional case, as it won't be used if the exception is thrown.

Only the modifications of `frontIndex` need to be in the `if`/`else`.

If you always increment, then you don't have to subtract in the comparison.  Saving one math operation in the common case and using the same number in the uncommon case.

#### Interfaces

There is a [Queue interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).  You might consider having this code implement that interface.  That will force you to name the operations as expected.

```
public class Queue2 implements Queue {
```

As is, someone used to the other queue might have trouble finding the equivalents of `add`, `remove`, and `peek`.

#### Bug?

In your `valueAtFront` and `valueAtRear` methods, you don't verify that there are elements in the queue.  So these may return garbage.  They should either throw an exception or return something like `null` when the queue is empty.

#### Resize

It's pretty common to allow queues to resize.  Something to consider for future development.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bug 1

Starting from an empty queue, if you enqueue and dequeue a single element it will advance `frontIndex` but not `rearIndex`.  This causes the queue to get out of sync.  For example, this snippet:

```
  Queue2 q = new Queue2(3);
  for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
      q.enqueue(i);
      System.out.println(q.dequeue());
  }
```

should output `0 1 2 3` but instead outputs `0 0 0 3`.

#### Bug 2

If you enqueue capacity-1 elements, then dequeue them all, and then enqueue one more element, there will be a bug.  You will move `rearIndex` back to 0 and put the new element there, but `frontIndex` will still be at capacity-1.  Therefore the next element you dequeue will be from the wrong spot.

#### No need for special case

The common problem for both of the bugs is that you have a special case in `enqueue()` that is unnecessary.  If instead of handling an empty queue in a special way, you simply did:

```
    queue[rearIndex++] = valueToAdd;
    if (rearIndex >= queue.length)
        rearIndex = 0;
```

then it would fix both of the bugs.